# Problem updating user profile photo in Firebase React Native and ASyncStorage

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I try to update the profile photo of a user who logs in, I get the session logged in with Asyncstorage and I reset it with a state in my APP.js but in another Tab, I get the session logged in with Asyncstorage but when updating the profile photo I get I get this error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 4):
TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is my App.js

```
const AuthenticatedUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider>
  );
};

function RootNavigator() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const [sesiones, setSesiones] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storeData = async (user) => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("cookie", JSON.stringify(user));
      } catch (e) {}
    };

    const obtenerSesion = async () => {
      try {
        const session = await AsyncStorage.getItem("cookie");
      setSesiones(JSON.parse(session));
      } catch (e) {}
    };

    if (user) {
      storeData(user);
      obtenerSesion();
    }

    if (!user) {
      obtenerSesion();
    }

    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (authenticatedUser) => {
      authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [user]);


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user || sesiones ? <AppNavigation /> : <GuestNavigation />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedUserProvider>
        <RootNavigator />
      </AuthenticatedUserProvider>

      <Toast />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is Profile.js
And from profile.js I obtain the user's session with Asyncstorage, the problem is that when I want to update the profile photo, what his blog tells you is that it is done like this: updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { photoURL: imageUrl });

But I get the session with Asyncstorage:

updateProfile(photoURLs, { photoURL: imageUrl });

photoURLs is the state where the user's session is saved but when updating it gives me this error:
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
 const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const imageBlob = [];
    const metadata = {
      contentType: "image/jpeg",
    };
    const img = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await img.blob();
    const storage = getStorage();
    const archivoRef = ref(storage, `avatar/${id()}`);
    uploadBytes(archivoRef, blob, metadata).then((snapshot) => {
      updatePhotoAvatar(snapshot.metadata.fullPath);
    });
  };

  const updatePhotoAvatar = async (imagePath) => {
    try {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const archivoRef = ref(storage, imagePath);
      const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(archivoRef);
      updateProfile(photoURLs, { photoURL: imageUrl });//error line
      setAvatar(imageUrl);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

When I get the session with Asycnstorage, I can't update the profile photo and so with the displayname, I get the same error. Code in React Native and Expo

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you've identified this line as your culprit.

```js
updateProfile(photoURLs, { photoURL: imageUrl });
```

This line creates a floating Promise because you've missed the `await` statement. Additionally, it is unclear what `photoURLs` is - is it an object? is it an
[`auth.User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface)?

For [`updateProfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updateprofile) to work correctly, you must pass in an `auth.User` object.

Based on this line, you are sometimes passing in a `auth.User` object and sometimes a plain JavaScript object (which is a [JSON-serializable version of `auth.User`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2d0a9f5fd921568bc76fcdee325b9ab5e6be8a58/packages/auth/src/core/user/user_impl.ts#L213-L236)):

```
user || sesiones ? <AppNavigation /> : <GuestNavigation />
```

To deal with this effectively, we should take a look at your authentication-related code and rework it so that this is more clear.

---

To start off, you should move the `onAuthStateChanged` logic into your `AuthenticatedUserProvider` component. This saves having to deal with `setUser` outside of your component which may lead to confusing behaviour.

```js
// ./components/AuthenticatedUserContext.jsx
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, User } from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthenticatedUserContext = createContext(null);

export default function AuthenticatedUserProvider({ children }) {
  // define state
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => auth.currentUser || undefined);
  
  // define helpers
  const loading = user === undefined;
  /** @type {Promise<User | null>} */
  const getUser = () => new Promise(resolve => { // <-- this helper is for later
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      unsubscribe();
      resolve(user);
    });
  });

  // define listeners
  // Note: You may want to swap out for onIdTokenChanged (by replacing
  // "onAuthStateChanged" with "onIdTokenChanged") depending on your use case.
  // Swapping means profile updates and token refreshes are detected, not just
  // sign-in and sign-out events.
  useEffect(() => onAuthStateChanged(auth, setUser), []);

  return (
    <AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        getUser,
        loading,
        /** @type {User | null} */
        user: user || null
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In the above code, this line:

```js
useEffect(() => onAuthStateChanged(auth, setUser), []);
```

replaces:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // ... this code is being moved ...

  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (authenticatedUser) => { // <-- shouldn't be async
    authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null);
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, [user]); // <-- this should be [], not [user]
```

Next, instead of using `useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext)`, you should follow the best practice of writing a custom hook for that context. In this below code, I define a hook called `useAuth()` (instead of the longer `useAuthenticatedUser()`):

```js
// ./components/AuthenticatedUserContext.jsx

/* code from above here */

export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  if (context === undefined) throw new Error("Missing parent AuthenticatedUserProvider");
  return context;
}
```

---

Next, because your `RootNavigator` is storing the `auth.User` object into `AsyncStorage`, you should move this logic into its own hook or make it a part of `AuthenticatedUserContext` or `useAuth()`. For the sake of this example, I'm going to choose to make it into its own hook but you should move this logic inside `AuthenticatedUserContext`.

For this hook, we can make the output `user` object always be the [JSON-serializable version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2d0a9f5fd921568bc76fcdee325b9ab5e6be8a58/packages/auth/src/core/user/user_impl.ts#L213-L236) of the [`auth.User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user#usertojson). If the actual `auth.User` object is needed (like in `updateProfile`), we'll make it accessible via `firebaseUser`.

In this code block, notice how the "read from AsyncStorage" and "update AsyncStorage" logic are kept separate in their own use effect calls. This is because we only need to read from AsyncStorage once, but we might need to update it multiple times.

```js
// ./components/AuthenticatedUserContext.jsx

/* code from above here */

// TODO: When user is signed out, clear cookie from AsyncStorage and set sesiones to `null`
export function useAuthWithAsyncStorage() {
  const { getUser, loading: firebaseLoading, user } = useAuth();
  const [sesiones, setSesiones] = useState(null);

  // define helpers
  const loading = firebaseLoading && sesiones == null;

  // handles keeping AsyncStorage#cookie updated
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) return; // do nothing, no user to store

    const objectUser = user.toJSON();
    const storedSesiones = JSON.stringify(objectUser);

    // store sesiones object
    AsyncStorage.setItem("cookie", storedSesiones)
      .catch((e) => { /* ignore */ });

    // update sesiones object
    setSesiones(objectUser);
  }, [user]);

  // handles reading from AsyncStorage#cookie once, only when first attached.
  // any further updates are handled by the useEffect above.
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribed = false;

    AsyncStorage.getItem("cookie")
      .then((value) => {
        if (!unsubscribed) return; // unsubscribed, do nothing
        setSesiones(JSON.parse(value))
      })
      .catch((e) => { /* ignore */ });

    return () => unsubscribed = true;
  }, []);
  
  return {
    firebaseUser: user, // pass through in case some of its methods are needed
    getUser,
    loading,
    user: user && user.toJSON() || sesiones
  }
}
```

---

Now with this handled in `AuthenticatedUserContext`, you can simplify your `RootNavigator` component down to:

```js
// ./components/RootNavigator.jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthWithAsyncStorage } from "./AuthenticatedUserContext";

export default function RootNavigator() {
  const { user } = useAuthWithAsyncStorage();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppNavigation /> : <GuestNavigation />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```js
// ./App.jsx
import AuthenticatedUserProvider from "./components/AuthenticatedUserContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedUserProvider>
        <RootNavigator />
      </AuthenticatedUserProvider>

      <Toast />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

Back to your problem component, you can now update your code to:

```js
const { getUser } = useAuthWithAsyncStorage();

// Note: `firebaseUser` may be null if the user is signed out or
// Firebase is still initializing, so we use getUser instead. This
// guarantees that we can talk to Firebase to perform the update.

const updatePhotoAvatar = async (imagePath) => {
  try {
    const firebaseUser = await getUser();
    if (!firebaseUser) throw new Error("Not logged in on server!");

    const storage = getStorage();
    const archivoRef = ref(storage, imagePath);
    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(archivoRef);
    await updateProfile(firebaseUser, { photoURL: imageUrl });
    setAvatar(imageUrl);
    setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```